# OpenCart Integrate wih template

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

Currently I using OpenCart v2.3.0.2, after me purchased the theme template, I tried follow the documentation but stuck on here.

Before met this errors, I get some similar error, which is 
    /var/www/html/public_html/catalog/view/theme/logancee/template/extension/module/featured.tpl on line 2

at the end i solve this error by deactive and active the extension. Now I stuck on the footer.tpl, which is this error.

Notice: Undefined variable: registry in /var/www/html/public_html/catalog/view/theme/logancee/template/common/footer.tpl on line 2
Notice: Undefined variable: registry in /var/www/html/public_html/catalog/view/theme/logancee/template/common/cart.tpl on line 2
Notice: Undefined variable: registry in /var/www/html/public_html/catalog/view/theme/logancee/template/common/header.tpl on line 2

Please advice me if you face this kind of error before.

Comment: I think, You need to contact it theme author support.

Answer (score 0):

You can end notices in the settings by setting `Display Errors` to `No`. Or you can back-trace these errors and variables and fix them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The theme you purchased is not prepared to handle some of the extensions, you have already installed.

I suggest you remove **ALL extensions**, **modifications** & **vQmods** that you have added and start adding them again by testing one by one to find out which one is giving you the error!

Also remove all your cached content & files before each step including your browser's cache.